# Git-annex auto merge symbolic links?

Tags: git, git-annex

Is it possible to merge two same file automatically?

For example, fileA and fileB are two same files. However, fileA is on PC and fileB is on Laptop. If I run `git annex import /path/to/fileA` and  `git annex import /path/to/fileB` together on each device, it will remain two different symbolic links in git archive tree after running `git annex sync`.

So, is there something like auto-merge tool that can remove one of those two symbolic link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git-annex stores its files based on their content hash. So if your two files `fileA` and `fileB` are identical, then they should both be recognised by git-annex as the same file. If they are not being recognised as the same file, then it suggests they might be slightly different. You could try comparing their hashes.

The git-annex docs have a tip page that explains how to combine multiple existing directories of content into a single repository, and it addresses exactly this topic.

https://git-annex.branchable.com/tips/migrating_two_seperate_disconnected_directories_to_git_annex/